# How to evaluate the integral $\iint_C \sin (x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to evaluate

$$\iint\limits_C  \sin (x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

where $C$ is the first quadrant, i.e.

$$\int\limits_0^\infty\int\limits_0^\infty  \sin (x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

where

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \sin x^2\, dx=\int\limits_0^\infty \cos x^2\, dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: The double integral you wrote *is not* over the entire plane but only over its first quadrant, so which one is it?

Comment: First quadrant, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that

$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \sin (x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=
\operatorname{Im}\left[\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty  \exp (i(x^2+y^2))\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\right]
$$

so, recalling that $\int f(x)\, \mathrm dx=\int f(y)\, \mathrm dy$

$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty  \exp (i(x^2+y^2))\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=
\int_0^\infty \exp(ix^2) \,\mathrm dx\int_0^\infty  \exp (iy^2)\,\mathrm dy=
\left(\int_0^\infty \exp(ix^2) \,\mathrm dx \right)^2
$$

Expanding the $\exp (ix^2)$ into $\cos x^2+i\sin x^2$, we find

$$
\left(\int_0^\infty \exp(ix^2) \,\mathrm dx \right)^2=
\left(\int_0^\infty \cos x^2+i\sin x^2 \,\mathrm dx \right)^2=\left((1+i)\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^2=
2i \cdot \frac{\pi}{8}=
i\frac{\pi}{4}
$$

So, taking the imaginary part, we see the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.  As an added bonus, we take the real part of that answer ($0$) to determine that $\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \cos (x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=0$

---

Here is an alternate proof:

If we use polar coordinates, we see ($x=r\cos \theta$, $x=r\sin \theta$, $\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = r\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$)

$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \sin (x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty r\sin (r^2)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta
$$

which diverges.  So, we introduce a "dummy function," $\exp(-\delta (x^2+y^2))$ that equals $1$ when $\delta \to 0$.  Then,

$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \exp(-\delta (x^2+y^2))\sin (x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty r\exp(-\delta r^2)\sin (r^2)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta=$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\infty r\exp(-\delta r^2)\sin (r^2)\,\mathrm dr
$$

Substituting $r^2=u$, $r \mathrm dr = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm du$, the integral becomes

$$\frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^\infty \exp(-\delta u)\sin (u)\,\mathrm du= \frac{\pi}{4(\delta^2+1)}$$

and we see that when $\delta \to 0$ the integral converges to $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Both the methods are very interesting!

Comment: @qwerty No problem!

Comment: @Potato: the integral converges, but not absolutely.  Just like rearranging a conditionally convergent series can give you a series that diverges or converges to any value, change of variables in a conditionally converging integral could give you different results.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I realize it's not (Lesbegue) integrable. Why does using an approximation to the identity like that produce the right answer?

Comment: Let $R_n$ be the quarter-annulus $\{(r,\theta): \sqrt{\pi (n-1)} < r < \sqrt{\pi n}, 0 \le \theta \le \pi/2\}$.  Then $J_n = \int_{R_n} \sin(x^2+y^2)\ dx dy = (\pi/2) \int_{\sqrt{\pi(n-1)}}^\sqrt{\pi n} r \sin(r^2)\ dr = (-1)^{n+1} \pi/2$, and essentially you're looking at $\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_n$.  Introducing $\exp(-\delta r^2)$ is essentially Abel's summability method, while using $\int_0^R 
\int_0^R dx \ dy$ is rather similar to Cesaro summability.

Comment: By this I mean, instead of a straight partial sum of the $J_n$ you have basically a weighted partial sum where the weights (essentially the fraction of the annulus included in the square) go gradually to $0$ at the upper end.

Comment: Abel and Cesaro summability always give the same result when the Cesaro sum converges, and I think something similar is happening here.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering about the underlying theory here, I posted a question about it you might find interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181971/abel-summability-of-integrals

Answer (score 11):

$$\begin{array}{c l}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2+y^2)dxdy & = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)\cos(y^2)+\cos(x^2)\sin(y^2)dxdy \\[10pt] & =\int_0^\infty\sin(x^2)dx\int_0^\infty\cos(y^2)dy \\ & \qquad~~~+\int_0^\infty\cos(x^2)dx\int_0^\infty\sin(y^2)dy \\[10pt] & = 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^2=\frac{\pi}{4}. \end{array}$$